# Angular: Submit form with data and image

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

I have a template driven form with some fields (e.g. name, birthday, place and more). An image should also be uploaded. Not all fields are required.

I tried it with the formData Object. Every field will be added like: 
`fileUploadForm.append('place', this.model.place);`
This works if the place-field has an input. If is it empty, i've got an "undefined".

Is it right to work with the formData Object or is there another way?
How can I add only filled fields to the formData Object?

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
model: any = {};

fileChanged(event) {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }

onSubmit() {
    let fileUploadForm: FormData  = new FormData();
    fileUploadForm.append('picture', this.file);
    fileUploadForm.append('name', this.model.name);
    fileUploadForm.append('birthday', this.model.birthday);
    ...
 this.CreateService.setData(fileUploadForm)
    .subscribe(
    ...
}

}
```

Comment: can you share the piece code where you struck on, so the we can get an idea about how the form defined

Comment: For Example: if the birthday field is empty, i've got an undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if statements, for example `if (this.file) fileUploadForm.append('picture', this.file);`. The best way is using angular reactive forms check this slackblitz example [angular reactive form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms)